# Compress Object/String through webservice and consume in .net compact framework

Tags: web-services, compact-framework, compression

We need to compress (or rather uncompress) some data we send to a pda client using a webservice.

Below I have a simple concept that will work if consumed by a regular .net app.

Unfortuantly, as the compact framework doesn't have the IO.Compression classes we can't see how this is possible without writing our own compression algorithms (as you'd don't have the ability to uncompress at the pda client end).

We have to use .net 2 only.

```
Dim c As New TestClass
c.Prop1 = "Test"
c.Prop2 = 1234

Dim XmlMemStream As New IO.MemoryStream
Dim mySerilizedObj As Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer = New Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(GetType(TestClass))

mySerilizedObj.Serialize(XmlMemStream, c)

Dim gz As New IO.Compression.GZipStream(XmlMemStream, IO.Compression.CompressionMode.Compress, False)
```

This needs to be done at application level and not Server Level (HTTP compression).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using [SharpZipLib](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SharpZipLib/) on the client, I have used it successfully on Compact Framework.